# Is the pod file mandatory in a third party package to use that in a react-native project new react-native version

Tags: react-native

Hi I tried to Install a Third Party Package in my React-native Project(0.61.5).
I am facing an Error with that Which doesn't have pods in it.
So Is it really necessary for a third party React-Native Package to include pods with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore auto linking in 3rd package.

your-project/react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  dependencies: {
    ...
    'your-package-name': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then you can manual add your package to your project.

Comment: Thank You I will Try In this Way